# Передать данные в 2 разных таблицы (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Существует 2 таблицы

```
- product (id, product_id, name, etc.)
- attributes (id, product_id, attribut_name)
```

При создании продукта нужно передать 2,3 значения input с name="attributes[]" в таблицу attributes

```
 id | product_id | name
 1  |      3     | attributess1
 2  |      3     | attributess2
```

Думаю нужно копать в сторону return $this->belongsToMany. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вам подойдет вот такой метод (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Сама модель продукта:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class);
    }
}
```

Создание:

```
$product = Product::create(['name' => 'Some product name' /*etc*/]);

$attributes = [];

foreach (\Request::get('attributes') as $attribute) {
    $attributes[] = new Attributes(['name' => $attribute]);
}
if (!empty($attribute)) {
    $product->attributes()->saveMany($attributes);
}
```